# Install elasticsearch rpm in different directory

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I want to install elasticsearch rpm in /opt/ instead of /usr/share. Im planning to use rpm relocate. But then I have to update all startup scripts manually??
Is there any easy way?

Comment: try to install by using tar

Comment: Tar will be working fine. But I prefer rpm, but needs that to installed in different location